# Inner Join or what else?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

What I have

```
Table A                                 Table B


ID    ID_Fruit    ,,, so on             ID      ID_Fruit   ID_CRATE  DateTime                
1     1002                              i_1     1002          1      2014-07-28 00:00.000
2     4534                              i_2     1002          2      2014-06-25 00:00.000
3     1243                              i_3     1243          NULL   2014-07-09 00:00.000
4     1003                              i_4     4534          1      2014-07-23 00:00.000
```

Result I want

```
ID    ID_Fruit    ,,, so on             ID      ID_Fruit    ID_CRATE     DateTime
1     1002                              i_1     1002           2      2014-06-25 00:00.000
2     4534                              i_4     4534           1      2014-07-23 00:00.000
```

What I am trying,

```
SELECT * FROM TABLEA
OUTER APPLY  
        (SELECT * FROM TableB WHERE TableB.ID_Fruit = TableA.ID_Fruit AND TableB.ID_CRATE IS NOT NULL) As Table_B
```

I want the only 1 row from several rows Table B based on closet DateTime

Comment: In Table I have 3 rows with ID_Fruit 1002, Now I want a Inner Join but with condition ON TableA.ID_Fruit = TableB.ID_Fruit  <---- but also with condition that only get matching row from table Row e.g. Order By DateTime column

Comment: Your last comment should maybe be contained in the question text. Also what do you mean by order by?

Comment: so you want only records of A with matching records in B and the oldest matching record of B?

Comment: What's your DBMS? MS SQL Server?

Comment: Yes, 2012 version of MS SQL SERVER

Answer (score 3):

Write as

```
;with CTE as 
( Select ID,
         ID_Fruit,
         ID_CRATE,
         [DateTime],
         Row_number() over ( partition by ID_Fruit order by [DateTime]  desc) as rownum
         from Table_B
 ) 
 select A.ID,A.ID_Fruit,C.ID,C.ID_CRATE,C.[DateTime] 
 from CTE C
 join Table_A A on A.ID_Fruit = C.ID_Fruit
 where C.rownum = 1 and isnull(ID_CRATE,'') <> ''
```

[Check Demo here..](http://rextester.com/IDAI27072)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.*, B.* FROM TABLE_A A, TABLE_B B
WHERE A.ID_Fruit = B.ID_Fruit
and B.DateTime IN (SELECT MAX(DateTime) from TABLE_B WHERE ID_Fruit = B.ID_Fruit)
```

Comment: An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.

Comment: I have just changed an '=' for IN.

Comment: Code only answer can be automatically sent do the Very Low Quality review list, please always add a description

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    TableAID,
    TableAID_Fruit,
    TableBID,
    TableBID_Fruit,
    ID_CRATE,
    DateTime
FROM
    (SELECT 
        TableA.ID TableAID,
        TableA.ID_Fruit TableAID_Fruit,
        TableB.ID TableBID,
        TableB.ID_Fruit TableBID_Fruit,
        TableB.ID_CRATE,
        TableB.DateTime,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TableB.ID_Fruit ORDER BY TableB.DateTime DESC) TableBOrder
    FROM
        TableA
        INNER JOIN TableB ON TableA.ID_Fruit = TableB.ID_Fruit
    ) Results
WHERE
    TableBOrder = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLEA
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM TableB
    WHERE TableB.ID_Fruit = TableA.ID_Fruit
    AND TableB.ID_CRATE IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY [DateTime]
) As Table_B
```

You were on the right track by using OUTER APPLY, but you will get all the rows from the left table, even the one with no matching row from the right table, so you may want to use CROSS APPLY instead (left rows with no matching row from right table are not returned).

You simply forgot to use TOP 1 and ORDER BY.

Here is a nice article about TOP N rows per group : http://sqlmag.com/database-development/optimizing-top-n-group-queries